# Using SetFileInformationByHandle to rename a file but it is deleted instead

Tags: winapi

I am using the `SetFileInformationByHandle()` function to rename a file.

I passed in `FileRenameInfo` with `ReplaceIfExists = TRUE` (a member of the `FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION` structure), but instead of renaming the file, it is deleting the file. I do not see any renamed file, and I do not get any error from the function call.

Comment: Please show your actual code

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you check whether the parameters in [`FileRenameInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_rename_info) are set correctly. Incorrect settings can cause the rename process to be deleted accidentally.

Here is a sample of using [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) to rename a file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto const& filepath = L"D:\\test\\file.txt";
    auto const& destpath = L"D:\\test\\other.txt";
    auto const f_handle = CreateFile(filepath,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (f_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to open: " << err;
        return err;
    }
    auto const destpath_bytes_with_null = sizeof(destpath);
    auto const struct_size = sizeof(FILE_RENAME_INFO) + destpath_bytes_with_null;
    FILE_RENAME_INFO* fri = (FILE_RENAME_INFO*)new BYTE[struct_size];
    fri->ReplaceIfExists = TRUE;
    fri->FileNameLength = destpath_bytes_with_null;
    fri->RootDirectory = NULL;

    std::memcpy(fri->FileName, destpath, destpath_bytes_with_null);

    BOOL res = SetFileInformationByHandle(f_handle, FileRenameInfo,
        fri, struct_size);
    if (!res)
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to rename file: " << err;
        return err;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "success";
}
```

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.